# calling another method in super class in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
class A
  def a
    puts 'in #a'
  end
end

class B < A
  def a
    b()
  end
  def b
    # here i want to call A#a.
  end
end
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
class B < A

  alias :super_a :a

  def a
    b()
  end
  def b
    super_a()
  end
end
```

Comment: To alias a class method, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925016/alias-method-and-class-methods-dont-mix

Comment: Is it possible that `alias` has been renamed to [`alias_method`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/alias_method) since this answer was written?

Comment: @JaredBeck it really has been renamed. So now it should be: alias_method :super_a :a

Comment: There is a strange thing. In the api doc for [ruby 2.1.2](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2) there is no alias method, but running code with alias works. Maybe I'm checking some wrong doc?

Comment: Why does this work? Why does this not alias `:super_a` to `B.a` and instead aliases it to `A.a`?

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš at the time you are creating the alias, `B.a` isn't defined yet... not the case if you put the `alias` below the `def a`

Answer (score 32):

There's no nice way to do it, but you can do `A.instance_method(:a).bind(self).call`, which will work, but is ugly.

You could even define your own method in Object to act like super in java:

```
class SuperProxy
  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj
  end

  def method_missing(meth, *args, &blk)
    @obj.class.superclass.instance_method(meth).bind(@obj).call(*args, &blk)
  end
end

class Object
  private
  def sup
    SuperProxy.new(self)
  end
end

class A
  def a
    puts "In A#a"
  end
end

class B<A
  def a
  end

  def b
    sup.a
  end
end
B.new.b # Prints in A#a
```

Comment: @klochner I disagree, this solution was exactly what I needed... reason: I wanted to generically call super method of a different method, but without the need to alias every single one that I wanted to be able to do this for, so a generic way to invoke super is pretty useful

Comment: Complicated to define once, simple to call it lots of times. That's better than vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't explicitly need to call A#a from B#b, but rather need to call A#a from B#a, which is effectively what you're doing by way of B#b (unless you're example isn't complete enough to demonstrate why you're calling from B#b, you can just call super from within B#a, just like is sometimes done in initialize methods.  I know this is kind of obvious, I just wanted to clarify for any Ruby new-comers that you don't have to alias (specifically this is sometimes called an "around alias") in every case.

```
class A
  def a
    # do stuff for A
  end
end

class B < A
  def a
    # do some stuff specific to B
    super
    # or use super() if you don't want super to pass on any args that method a might have had
    # super/super() can also be called first
    # it should be noted that some design patterns call for avoiding this construct
    # as it creates a tight coupling between the classes.  If you control both
    # classes, it's not as big a deal, but if the superclass is outside your control
    # it could change, w/o you knowing.  This is pretty much composition vs inheritance
  end
end
```