# alias_method and class_methods don't mix?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, alias-method

I've been trying to tinker with a global Cache module, but I can't figure out why this isn't working.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

This is the error:

```
NameError: undefined method `get' for module `Cache'
    from (irb):21:in `alias_method'
```

... generated by this code:

```
module Cache
  def self.get
    puts "original"
  end
end

module Cache
  def self.get_modified
    puts "New get"
  end
end

def peek_a_boo
  Cache.module_eval do
    # make :get_not_modified
    alias_method :get_not_modified, :get
    alias_method :get, :get_modified
  end

  Cache.get

  Cache.module_eval do
    alias_method :get, :get_not_modified
  end
end

# test first round
peek_a_boo

# test second round
peek_a_boo
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The calls to `alias_method` will attempt to operate on **instance** methods. There is no instance method named `get` in your `Cache` module, so it fails.

Because you want to alias **class** methods (methods on the metaclass of `Cache`), you would have to do something like:

```
class << Cache  # Change context to metaclass of Cache
  alias_method :get_not_modified, :get
  alias_method :get, :get_modified
end

Cache.get

class << Cache  # Change context to metaclass of Cache
  alias_method :get, :get_not_modified
end
```

Comment: You don't need the whole `Cache.module_eval do class << self` — you can just write `class << Cache`.