# Calling a parent::method from a child::method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Good day, i'm new to ruby. I want to know how to run a parent method from a method of a child class ?
in java it would be like

```
class Child
  ..
  def something_else
    super.something
  end
end
```

and in php

```
parent::method_name();
```

And could you tell me how to do it in Ruby?
found only this, and it's kind of ugly using **alias_method_chain**

Comment: Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251178/calling-another-method-in-super-class-in-ruby

Comment: Yep, thanks for that. i hope ruby can do better than this, cause it's not as elegant as the rest of ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as **Taiki** suggested the comment in another thread stated

```
class B < A

  alias :super_a :a

  def a
    b()
  end
  def b
    super_a()
  end
end
```

hope there are other ways...

**UPDATE:**

at long last, call super() instead of super_a(). not sure what it does completely though