# Ruby: how to get parent method that redefined in children class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can i get Base's "hello" method from Up class in code below?

```
class Base
  def hello
    p 'hello from Base'
  end
end

class Up < Base
  def hello_orig
    # how to call hello from Base class?
  end

  def hello
    p 'hello from Up'
  end
end

u = Up.new
u.hello_orig # should return 'hello from Base'
```

Comment: Do you want to call `hello_orig` directly or do you want to use the original method (as implemented in base class) in the subclass `hello`? If so, stick with `super` in `Up#hello`

Comment: I need to call `hello_orig`, because `hello` in Up class implement own logic

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling another method in super class in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251178/calling-another-method-in-super-class-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
class Base
  def hello
    p 'hello from Base'
  end

end

class Up < Base
  def hello_orig
    Base.instance_method(:hello).bind(self).call

  end

  def hello
    super() 
    p 'hello from Up'
  end

end

u = Up.new
u.hello_orig # should return 'hello from Base' or
u.hello
```

Comment: You can call `super()` from hello also

Comment: `super` in my case can't be used because `hello` in Up class should have different behaviour. But the variant in your answer works, thank you)

Answer (score 4):

You can use aliasing as well.

```
class Base
  def hello
    p 'hello from Base'
  end
end

class Up < Base
  alias hello_orig hello

  def hello
    p 'hello from Up'
  end
end

u = Up.new
u.hello_orig # should return 'hello from Base'
```

Comment: Interesting, how would use then create an alias for the `hello` function in `Up` ?

Comment: after defining the hello, alias new_hello hello

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you explain how `alias` method works internally or give me a link?